# Hovering not properly / jump to section onclick wtihout anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a jump tab for my portfolio website, but i'm stuck at this small feature.

[image]

```
<ul class="section">
   <li><span>home</span></li>
   <li><span>about</span></li>
   <li><span>project</span></li>
   <li><span>contact</span></li>
<ul>
```

```
#main .section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

#main .section li {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

#main .section li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(78, 78, 78);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

#main .section li span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    right: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0;
}

#main .section li span:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

First, Text is only shown when I hover on `span`. Text wouldn't be shown when I hover on `li` which is a circle. Am I missing something here?

Second, I'm stuck at the actual function which it should jump to the section. I'm trying to use `scrollIntoView` method, but how could I target multiple elements in one function?
This is what I've been doing so far, but it sure doesn't work.

```
let jumpbtn = document.querySelectorAll(".section li");

function jump(){
    for(var i = 0; i < jumpbtn.length; i++){
        jumpbtn[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            this.id.scrollIntoView({behavior: "Smooth"});
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now hover the circle to view text also :)

try this

```
.section li:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

instead of

```
.section li span:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Then
I passed the **class** of each **li** in `onclick()` event.

```
<li onclick="jump(this.className)" class="home">
```

then, get **target element** by this **class name** having target element's **id** by,

```
function jump(TarId){
   var target = document.getElementById(TarId);
   document.getElementById(TarId).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
}
```

**`Live Demo`**

```js
function jump(TarId){
   var target = document.getElementById(TarId);
   document.getElementById(TarId).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
}
```

```css
.section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(25% - 100px);
    right: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 10;
}

.section li {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.section li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(78, 78, 78);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.section li span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    right: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0;
}

.section li:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
#main{
    background:#111;
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
}
.content{
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:200px;
}
h1{
  color:#00cc00;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <ul class="section">
     <li onclick="jump(this.className)" class="home"><span>home</span></li>
     <li onclick="jump(this.className)" class="about"><span>about</span></li>
     <li onclick="jump(this.className)" class="project"><span>project</span></li>
     <li onclick="jump(this.className)" class="contact"><span>contact</span></li>
  <ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div id="home">
    <h1>Home Content</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<p>
  </div>

  <div id="about">
    <h1>about Content</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<p>
  </div>

  <div id="project">
    <h1>project Content</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<p>
  </div>

  <div id="contact">
    <h1>contact Content</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet, it will helpful for you.

```js
  function moveToDiv(target){
            document.getElementById(target).scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        }
```

```css
    .section{
    display:block;
    }
    .section-area{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 10px solid red;
    background: gray;
    font-size: 30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:block;
    }
```

```html
  <ul class="section">
       <li onclick="moveToDiv('home')"><span>home</span></li>
       <li onclick="moveToDiv('about')"><span>about</span></li>
       <li onclick="moveToDiv('project')"><span>project</span></li>
       <li onclick="moveToDiv('contact')"><span>contact</span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="section-area" id="home">Home</div>
    <div class="section-area" id="about">About</div>
    <div class="section-area" id="projects">Projects</div>
    <div class="section-area" id="contact">Contact</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that method, but was looking for another method that won't leave #foo on url

Comment: @HobbitY Solution updated can you please check it. thank you.